# Structural Correspondence Learning for Domain Adaptation - how is the augmented data formed?

Tags: machine-learning

Structural Correspondence Learning (SCL) is a method for dealing with domain adaptation (different data distributions in the training and testing sets). It was proposed by [Blitzer et al.](http://john.blitzer.com/papers/emnlp06.pdf) but I am having difficulty understanding exactly how the data is represented in this technique.

SCL deals with Domain Adaptation by choosing *m* 'pivot features' which are consistent across both domains, then for each one, creating a binary classification task, using the remaining features to predict whether or not a the pivot in question will appear in the instance.

The weight vectors which were learned in this task form *W*,a *m*x*n* matrix , where *n* is the number of original features. Each element corresponds to the strength of correlation between one original feature with one pivot.

Singular value decomposition is applied to *W*, factorising it into UDV<sup>T</sup>. θ is then formed by taking the first *h* elements of U<sup>T</sup>.

θ is added to the original feature set; from the paper:

> 'For training instance *t*, the augmented feature vector will contain all the original features x<sub>t</sub> plus the new shared features θx<sub>t</sub>.

Now, the part which I don't understand:

As far as I can tell, θ has dimensions *h* x *n*. The original features have dimensions *m* x *n*.

So how can we get θx<sub>t</sub> for each of the original *m* instances in the original dataset when θ is *h*x*n*?

Answer (score 1):

Is it not that the original feature vectors, **x**, are *n x 1*, so that when we do **θx** we get a *h x 1* vector, which is then appended to the original?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @v90a. Was this intended as an answer to the OP's question, 
a comment requesting clarification from the OP, or a 
new question of your own? Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide 
answers to the original question. You will be able to comment anywhere when 
your reputation is >50. If you have a new question, click the gray `ASK QUESTION` 
at the top of the page & ask it there, then we can help you properly. Since you're 
new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users.

Comment: Just commenting because I recently read the paper: This answer, masked as a question, is actually correct. The only thing amiss here is the form. Stated as an actual answer: 
"the original feature vectors, x, are n x 1, so that when we do θx we get a h x 1 vector, which is then appended to the original"

Answer (score 0):

for dataSet X,every row of X represent a instance, which can be seen as a row vector,but x is generally a column vector by default. that is, there is a transformation.

Comment: Hi there. Your question is not clear at this stage. Can you please edit your question to make it clear what your data is, and what is the question you need answering